# Where is the Look and Feel JSP file?

Tags: liferay-6.2, liferay-hook

There is this *Look and Feel* option in every portlet settings:

[image: Look and Feel potlet settings]

I want to create hook for this tab. Which JSP file do I have to override?
How can I add my custom field in this tab (like *Use Custom Title*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to find such files:

1. Look into `src/content/Language.properties` for a term from your screen with high significance, e.g. `Use Custom Title`:

   ```
   ...
   use-custom-title=Use Custom Title
   ...
   ```
2. Now search for a file that contains the key, in our case `use-custom-title`:

   ```
   portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp
   ```

That is indeed the file you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. i got the file. i added a custom text box there. how to store its value in db. I am using preferences--headerColor-- but its not getting saved in portlet preferences.

Comment: You will need to override `com.liferay.portlet.portletconfiguration.action.UpdateLookAndFeelAction`

Comment: will it be Ext or a hook? any reference how to create this. when i am creating the hook i am extending BaseStrutsPortletAction